# A projectile has been shot into the atmosphere. Find the polynomial that interpolates the speed and acceleration in function of time.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, numerical-calculus, error-propagation

This is the table (tempo = time, velocidade = speed, aceleracao = acceleration)

[image]

I used Newton's interpolation to get the polynomial (5th degree).

I got
$$102 + 138(x-15) + (-124/15)(x-15)^2 + (289/225)(x-15)^2(x-30) + (-0.0689)(x-15)^2(x-30)^2 + (0.0048)(x-15)^2(x-30)^2(x-45)$$

I tested this in my calculator and the values for p(15) and p(30) are correct but p(45) is completely wrong.

Then I got the derivative to test the derivatives
$$14341.5 - 2226.13 x + 122.896 x^2 - 2.8676 x^3 + 0.024 x^4$$

p'(15) and p'(30) are correct, albeit with a slight error, but p'(45) is very off (I got 132 point something).

Is this normal? Is it possible to get a better estimate for this?

My calculations:

[image]

Comment: The physicist in me cringes at this problem. Is this projectile being shot into the atmosphere on some planet with 10 times Earth's gravity? Since the speed and acceleration have the same sign, it's falling, and around 30' is it in some super rarefied strata of the atmosphere such that its acceleration is suddenly 30% greater than it was before or after? Whatever book gave you this problem should not have called this a projectile...

Comment: @jwimberley It was my professor. It's refreshing to find a place where people see through his pendantry haha

Comment: A suggestion for your question -- few people (myself included) are going to read through handwritten work to search for an error. As for your problem,

Comment: @jwimberley : You can, if you dare, look deeper into the second (first computed) column. The average acceleration from 0' to 15' is 14, a magnitude below the point values given.

Comment: In the first column where you transcribe the velocity values, the last two entries read as 179 and 175(?), whereas in the table you have 420. And you use the value 179 in the difference quotient beside it, and thus in all further computations. Is the computed value for $p(45)$ close to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the table correctly, with $p(x_2)=420$, you get
$$\small\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
p[x_0]=102&p[x_0,x_0]=138&p[x_0,x_0,x_1]=-8.2667&p[x_0,x_0,x_1,x_1]=1.28444\\
&p[x_0,x_1]=14&p[x_0,x_1,x_1]=11&p[x_0,x_1,x_1,x_2]=-0.74844\\
p[x_1]=312&p[x_1,x_1]=179&p[x_1,x_1,x_2]=-11.4533&p[x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2]=1.36267\\
&p[x_1,x_2]=7.2&p[x_1,x_2,x_2]=8.9867\\
p[x_2]=420&p[x_2,x_2]=142
\end{array}$$
cont.
$$\small\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
&p[x_0,x_0,x_1,x_1,x_2]= -0.067763&p[x_0,x_0,x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2]=0.004604\\
&p[x_0,x_1,x_1,x_2,x_2]=0.070370&
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Given the 6 degrees of freedom and the six constraints, the interpolation can be exact, if it is possible at all (which is always a possibility in practice, but unlikely for a homework problem). Any small inaccuracies you see are the result of either errors in your work or the fact that you're calculating with decimal approximations. I'm not sure where your -0.0689 and and 0.0048 terms came from. You should double-check your computations using precise fractions -- note that since all the constraints are integral, all your powers of 15 in denominators *should* cancel out.

If it turns out there is still an issue after checking your computations, I'll suggest an alternate cross-check method. Letting the 6 coefficients of a fifth degree polynomial be unknowns, the 6 constraints you have from a system of linear equations in those coefficients. Converting this into a matrix equation, you should be able to solve it through Gaussian elimination. You can make life easier for yourself by also having the polynomial be a function of not $t$ but $z = (t-15)/15$, so that all the constraints are at $z = 0$, $1$, and $2$.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem comes for the conversion to decimals (notice that $45^5=184528125$ and any error on the last coefficient will have a dramatic impact.

Since I suppose that you used matrix calculations, you must have arrived at
$$v=-68178+\frac{69497 t}{5}-\frac{26902 t^2}{25}+\frac{88873 t^3}{2250}-\frac{11633
   t^4}{16875}+\frac{259 t^5}{56250}$$ which reproduces exactly the values of speed and acceleration.

Deriving, we have
$$\frac{69497}{5}-\frac{53804 t}{25}+\frac{88873 t^2}{750}-\frac{46532
   t^3}{16875}+\frac{259 t^4}{11250}$$ which ,concerted to decimals, gives
$$13899.4-2152.16 t+118.497 t^2-2.75745 t^3+0.0230222   t^4$$ which are quite different to the ones you posted.